# Calculate series with continual roots in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, math, series

Looking to compute the following **series** in JavaScript:

[image]

Specifically, the code will be used to validate the RHS. The point is to explore the behavior of the series with an increasing number of terms in the expression.

The following JS is a start:

```
var res = 0;
for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    res += Math.sqrt(1 + ???)
}
```

... but I'm not sure how to **continuously take a root of a root of a root** .... in JS?

A programmatic way of accomplishing:

```
Math.sqrt(1 + Math.sqrt(1 + Math.sqrt(1 + Math.sqrt(1 + ....))))
```

for an arbitrary number of roots.

I was thinking something like this:

```
var res = [];
for(var i=1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if(res.length > 0) {
        res.push(Math.sqrt(1 + res[i - 1]))
    } else {
        res.push(Math.sqrt(1 + 0))
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

@Slevin 's answer using a recursion worked. I had to adjust it slightly to capture each value in an array. Here is the array version:

```
res= [];
function getRoots(number) {
    if (number === 1) {  
        var res_1 = Math.sqrt(1);      
        res.push(res_1)
        return(res_1)    
    } else {
        var res_2 = Math.sqrt(1 + getRoots(number - 1));
        res.push(res_2);
        return(res_2)
    }
};

getRoots(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but could this be your solution?:

```
function getRoots(number) {
    if (number === 1) return Math.sqrt(1);
    return Math.sqrt(1 + getRoots(number - 1));
}

let result = getRoots(1000);
console.log(result);
```

Here recursion is used to get your result. The function calls itself aslong untill the 1000 times are done.

Here an updated version with modern JS (const instead of var to declare the array) and using one-liners to update the array and return the value:

```
const results = [];

const getRoots = number => {
    if (number === 1) return results[results.push(Math.sqrt(1)) - 1];
    return results[results.push(Math.sqrt(1 + getRoots(number - 1))) - 1];
};

getRoots(1000);

for (let res of results)
    console.log(res);
```

FYI: Array.prototype.push() returns the new length of the array, so we use this value to return the pushed calculation back.

Comment: Because the code is used to validate the RHS. The point is to explore the behavior of the series with increasing number of terms in the expression.

Comment: Updated with recursive function, that should do the job :)

Comment: The recursion functions seems correct, however I need the individual terms returned in an array. I'm trying to push each result of the recursion with your function.

Comment: Got it. Yes this works. I've added the array version to my question as an update.Thanks.